# promise logic with sql in nodejs when making calls to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have the code below that is reliant on two api calls to two different tables. It first  gets data from database, gets an id from there, makes another call to another table, gets data from there and appends it to each value from the first call. The code works fine in theory but I just need to be able to resolve the final product by creating a chain of events. The final resolve should wait for the entire code to finish executing and then return the value of first_call.

Here is my code. Let me know how I can modify it.

**Updated code**

```
function getUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var sql = `SELECT p.customer, p.fname, p.lname, p.email, p.user, c.name AS organizationName, c.email AS organizationEmail c.did AS phoneNumber FROM people AS p LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON c.id = p.customer`;
      console.log(sql)
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        resolve(result); 
      });
    });
  }
```

**Old code**

```
function getUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var first_call = []
      var sql = `SELECT customer, fname, lname, email, user FROM people`;
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        first_call = result
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < first_call.length; i++) {
        var sql2 = `SELECT name, email, did FROM customers WHERE id = ${first_call[i].customer}`;
        con.query(sql2, function (err, result2) {
          first_call[i].organizationName = result2[0].name;
          first_call[i].organizationEmail = result2[0].email;
          first_call[i].phoneNumber = result2[0].did;
        });
      }

      resolve(first_call); 
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you just combine the two queries into a single JOIN?

Comment: You need to put the `for` loop inside the callback function of the first query.

Comment: @Barmar ideally i would like to make it into one query. How would I be able to do this with my use case though because i need the response from the first sql statement

Comment: Didn't you see the answer I posted? It includes the combined query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to combine the two queries with a JOIN:

```
SELECT p.customer, p.fname, p.lname, p.email, p.user, c.name AS organizationName, c.email AS organizationEmail, c.did AS phoneNumber
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON c.id = p.customer
```

But if you really want two queries, here's how to rewrite your promise code using `async` and `await`.

You should also use a parameter in the SQL rather than substituting a variable.

```js
async function getUsers() {
  var first_call = []
  var sql = `SELECT customer, fname, lname, email, user FROM people`;
  first_call = await con.query(sql)
  var sql2 = `SELECT name, email, did FROM customers WHERE id = ?`;
  for (let i = 0; i < first_call.length; i++) {
    let result2 = await con.query(sql2, [first_call[i].customer]);
    first_call[i].organizationName = result2[0].name;
    first_call[i].organizationEmail = result2[0].email;
    first_call[i].phoneNumber = result2[0].did;
  }

  return first_call;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Your sql code works in my sql editor in DBBeaver but in mynodejs environment it throws this error:

Comment: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c.did AS phoneNumber FROM people AS p LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON c.id = p.custo' at line 1 @barmar

Comment: You're missing a comma after `AS organizationEmail`

Comment: The error message told you exactly where the problem is. Isn't obvious to compare that part of the query with mine, to see if you copied something wrong?

Comment: Please put the original code back in the question. My answer makes no sense without it.

Comment: sorry about that put it back in!